# can't find error my sollution to makeBricks problem java

Tags: java

I found a simple Java exercise and I answered it, yet there seems to be an issue with my code and I can't seem find the problem. Please point me towards the issue:

The problem is:

We want to make a row of bricks that is `goal` inches long. We have a number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each). Return `true` if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the given bricks. This is a little harder than it looks and can be done without any loops.

And I made this function as answer:

```
 public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
  if (small>=goal) return true;
  if ((goal>=5) && (big>=1)){  makeBricks(small,big-1,goal-5);}
  return false;
}
```

Yet when running it on https://codingbat.com/prob/p183562 it says that it's wrong and it all looks correct to me.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: `return` will fix your short-term problem, but this approach throws a stack overflow on `makeBricks(2, 1000000, 100003) → false`. Hint: multiplication.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `return` statement fixes your technical problem of being unable to determine the truth value of calls further down the stack, but that's a linear solution to a problem that can be solved in constant time with basic math:

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
    return big * 5 + small >= goal && goal % 5 <= small;
}
```

The idea here is to first determine if all of our bricks combined meets or exceeds the goal: `big * 5 + small >= goal`. If we can't satisfy this equation, we're definitely out of luck.

However, this is overly optimistic and does not account for cases when we have sufficient blocks to exceed the goal but not enough small blocks to remove some number of larger blocks and meet the goal. Testing `goal % 5 <= small` ensures that we have enough small blocks to bridge the gap of 5 that will be left as each large block is removed.

If that's still not clear, let's examine an edge case: `makeBricks(3, 2, 9)`. Our goal is 9 and we have 3 small blocks and 2 large ones. Combining our entire arsenal gives a total of 13, which seems sufficient to meet the goal. However, if we omit one of our large blocks, the closest we can get is 8. If we omit all of our small blocks, the closest we can get is 10. No matter what we do, the goal is one block out of reach.

Let's check that against our formula: `9 mod 5 == 4`, which is 1 more than our number of small blocks, 3, and matches our hand computation. We should return `false` on this input. On the other hand, if we had 1 extra small block, `9 % 5 == small` would be true, and we'd have just enough blocks to bridge the gap.

Answer (score 2):

Put a `return` in front of your recursive call:

```
return makeBricks(small,big-1,goal-5);
```

Comment: ty very much been having a headacke over this

Comment: yes im waiting for 10min to be over  to be able to accept the answer

Comment: For makeBricks(2, 1000000, 100003) ,I get StackOverflowError (line:3) ( i think the recursion is what is causing this , any recommendations on the subject ?)

Comment: @OUSSAMAHEDDA not use recursion in the first place but a `while` loop instead

Comment: yes i solved it with this :<br/>
`
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
  if (small>=goal) return true;
   if (((small >=(goal%5)) && (big>=(goal/5))) || ((small>=(goal-5*big)) && (goal>=5*big)))
{ return  true;}
  return false;
}`

Comment: @OUSSAMAHEDDA that is even better :)